# Getting a `open_loop': HTTP redirection loop error with Ember-Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I am trying to run :

```
rails new emberRailsApp -m http://emberjs.com/edge_template.rb
```

But this is the output I am getting :

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open-uri.rb:231:in `open_loop': HTTP redirection loop: http://emberjs.com/edge_template.rb (RuntimeError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open-uri.rb:149:in `open_uri'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open-uri.rb:688:in `open'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open-uri.rb:34:in `open'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions.rb:218:in `apply'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:101:in `apply_rails_template'
    from (eval):1:in `apply_rails_template'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `block in invoke_all'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `map'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `invoke_all'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/group.rb:232:in `dispatch'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/commands/application.rb:43:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:58:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:58:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/cli.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:58:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:58:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/bin/rails:23:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
```

Anyone, any idea with regards to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it. All had to do was run it via sudo.

Comment: how is the sudo access related to `HTTP redirection loop`?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. But it just worked. I too was wondering the same thing. Well, I guess computers can be funny sometimes :P

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem without sudo and rvm by just downloading the file and referencing it locally:

```
touch local_rails_ember_template.rb
curl http://emberjs.com/edge_template.rb > local_rails_ember_template.rb
rails new my_app_name -m local_rails_ember_template.rb
```